# It make sense to index a datetime field?

Tags: mysql

I have a table approaching the billions of records and with various indexed fields, one of which is a datetime that I use only for selecting records between two dates, and never for a join.

Does it make sense or is it possible to de-index it?

Comment: You can certainly create an index on a date field, and you can drop the index if you decide you want to. You'd have run tests to determine if having the index speeds up your queries. Best of luck.

Comment: You use the datetime field as filter in your queries. Of course it makes sense!

Comment: My doubt is that i never use something like SELECT WHERE Date = '2017/11/25 20:30', but in a range between two dates. I know that can't do wrong keeping it, but if it doen't provide any improvement I want to remove it. I know that I must do some test before, but just the setup will take some hour, so for the moment I wanted to know "on a theoretical base".

Answer (score 2):

On the face of it, it seems a good idea if it is used in a WHERE clause.

The way to find out if it would benefit would be to view the execution plan of one the queries before and after adding it and see if it has made a difference.

An index may still be ignored if the query is returning a large amount of rows in the index as it would more efficient in that case to do am index scan rather than an index seek